# How to Force Oracle to use indexes in inline view of a query with "order by" clause

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g, sql-order-by, inline-view

Oracle 11g

I have a query which schematically looks like this:

```
select *
from
(
  --My inline view
  select ...
)
order by
  field1, field2;
```

My inline view is a complicated query from several tables with indexes.

If I execute inline view only, Oracle using indexes and query executes fast.
But If execute whole query, Oracle doesn't using indexes and query executes slow.

I have found one solution (using two steps):

```
-- 1. I just creating temp table from my inline view (no sorting)
create global temporary table tmp
on commit preserve rows
as
--My inline view (Here Oracle using indexes and query runs fast)
select ...

-- 2. Now I sort it (result set is not very large and this runs also fast)
select * 
from tmp
order by
  field1, field2;
```

But I would like to use more simple way without temp tables, if it possible.

I tried to use "with" - no luck, same problem.

I'm sorry for not posting actual query. It is just to complicated and it is very difficult to write sample script illustrating the problem.

**Upd**

Subquery is multiple `UNION ALL` from tables `SLOT, SLOT_O` left joined with table `TLG_INFORM`.
`TLG_INFORM` has an index `IDX_TLG_INFORM_PAIR`, which is used without `ORDER BY` and not used With `ORDER BY`.

Execution plans:

Without `ORDER BY`
[image: Without ORDER BY]

With `ORDER BY`
[image: With ORDER BY]

I tried using `WITH` and hint `/*+MATERIALIZE*/`. No luck. Also, with hint `/*+MATERIALIZE*/` index didn't used without `ORDER BY` too.

Materialized without `ORDER BY`.
[image: Materialized without ORDER BY]

Materialized with `ORDER BY`.
[image: Materialized with ORDER BY]

Comment: Try eliminating the outer query and add the `ORDER BY ` to the inline view, e.g. `SELECT ... (inline view code)... ORDER BY FIELD1, FIELD2`. Other option: convert the inline view to a CTE: `WITH cteIV AS (<inline view code here>) SELECT * FROM cteIV ORDER BY FIELD1, FIELD2`. Without specifics such as tables, indexes, and sample data which demonstrates the problem I don't see a way to be specific about this. Best of luck.

Comment: I tried both: sorting inline view code itself and "with". All the same.

Comment: What `optimizer_mode` are you using? This sounds like a `first_rows%` style plan that’s now leading on an index that covers your order by clause.

Comment: `optimizer_mode` is `ALL_ROWS`

Comment: Gather statistics on all tables involved and try running it again. Then - is there an index on (FIELD1, FIELD2)? If not, add one, gather statistics, and try again. Also, check the plan to see what's going on - but without specifics, again, there's little we can do but guess. So I guess that's about it.

Comment: I suggest posting both complete execution plans so we can see what Oracle though about your query

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its very hard to find out without specifics. Posting sample script is also very difficult due to complexity of a query, so my solution, as I posted earlier, is temporary table.

Result of complex query into temporary table.
And select from this table with sorting needed.
Probably, this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may indicate that the DBMS does not know your data well enough. Updating table statistics may help here.

But maybe it's really a flaw in the optimizer. You should be able to circumvent this issue with a materialized CTE:

```
with my_inline_view as (select /*+materialize*/ ...)
select *
from my_inline_view
order by field1, field2;
```

Comment: I tried. And I got strange result. With `/*MATERIALIZE*/` hint in subquery it doesn't use index in both cases: with `order by` and without `order by` and executes slow. It seems, that `/*MATERIALIZE*/` hint "supresses" using indexes. Without `/*MATERIALIZE*/` hint and without `order by` it uses index and runs fast.